# PC won't boot from USB medium

Tags: boot, usb, bios, uefi, acer-aspire

So I bought my laptop with a legitimate copy of Windows 8.1, replaced it with Debian 9/Stretch and then dual booted it with Android X86, after that came Windows 10 and Arch. Quadruple booting was no problem. I eventually deleted all the Linux partitions and removed everything related to GRUB and my linux OSs. After 2 weeks, I craved for linux. Now here's the problem: I can't boot from any USB medium. Be it a pendrive, USB stick or an SD card, it won't allow it. My PC uses UEFI booting and I have disabled secure boot. I also disabled Fast Startup, yet it didn't change anything. I saw from diskpart that it displayed my SD card as a non-bootable drive. This might be due to the fact that I'm used to see a 'bootable' flag in GParted, but I also heard that it's a bug in GParted itself and that a GPT drive actually is a bootable drive in itself. Any help on booting from USB?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you do not use an USB 3.0 port or USB 3.0 flash drive. Often, it does not boot on it. I think you checked that! ;)

Comment: Wait, an SD card can either be a 3.0 or 2.0 flash drive?

Comment: No. SD card cannot but you can insert an SD card in an USB 3.0 Adapter. I do not know. Which software do you use to create your bootable USB (UNetbootin, Rufus...)?

Comment: Also, I use rufus as it is the only software I actually trust on getting me a bootable UEFI drive. For my linux based OSs, I use dd.